# Does my ERD look well designed?

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd

I am making a database at no cost for a local dance school. I'm still very new this would like to be sure that I designed it appropriately.

From the front end, the parent will: fill out their personal info, create a student for each child and, an account number will be assigned to the parent. Each student will have an annual fee(s) attached to their name. Student will be enrolled in classes by the parent and, I plan to total the costs by adding together each unique enrolment for a student.

I think the diagram can explain the rest. Have I designed done this properly?

[image]

Comment: Can a student be both male and female?  Neither?

Comment: Rather than having 3 sets of fields for "parents" have N rows with one set of fields.  Ditto for phone numbers.

Comment: You may want a table for "Family" -- to handle multiple parents _and_ multiple children in the same family.  This might consume Account.

Comment: A many-to-many table is usually just 2 columns; no need for the third.

Comment: If you want more review, post `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the indexes, etc.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks,RJ . Here's the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uuwAy0fG) of my create tables. I could not figure out a way to post them here correctly.

Comment: @RickJames Can explain having N rows with having one set of fields? I'm looking it up now but, you may be able to give me a more concise answer.

Comment: @RickJames Would "N rows" mean having a table for a parent and, a table for phone numbers?

Comment: True innovations are rare in software. Google "open source school management software" or "college" and see what they've done. I did and got 44 million hits. You should be able to get a few good ideas there. Copy the bits your need - discard the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PRIMARY KEY (`STUDENT_ID`, `ANNUAL_FEES_ANNUAL_FEE_ID`, `PARENTS_PARENTS_ID`, `PARENTS_ACCOUNTS_ACCOUNT_ID`),
```

It seems like `Students` would have `student_id` as its `PRIMARY KEY`.

`DECIMAL(4,2)` -- do you want to limit things to $99.99?

This is what I mean about many-to-many relation table:

```
CREATE TABLE XtoY (
    # No surrogate id for this table
    x_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to one table
    y_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to the other table
    # Include other fields specific to the 'relation'
    PRIMARY KEY(x_id, y_id),            -- When starting with X
    INDEX      (y_id, x_id)             -- When starting with Y
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

What is a "Performance_Student"?

Parents table:

```
parent_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
family_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
type ENUM('mother', 'father', 'guardian', 'grandparent', 'other'),
`LAST_NAME` VARCHAR(35) NULL,
`FIRST_NAME` VARCHAR(35) NULL,
`EMAIL` VARCHAR(50) NULL
PRIMARY KEY(parent_id)
```

The Phones table would have parent_id and be many_to_1.

Comment: Thanks again, RJ. I'm still looking over your advice but, to answer your question - a performance student pays a bulk price for advanced classes. The performance student can attend as many of these bulk classes per week as he/she desires.

Comment: One of the requirements I'll have for parental contacts is that I need to store phone numbers as father's number, mother's number and, Guardian's number. Doesn't mean that I should have a family table with a family table(family ID key ) with a reference to a parent table? That way numerous "parents" can be stored under one family.

Comment: I hope that I have gotten you to think outside your original ER box.  Now you need to sketch out possible layouts for parents, phones, etc, and decide which one makes the most sense.  Compare them based on flexibility (or lack), meeting requirements easily or not (such as phone number tied to particular parental-unit), etc.  You will probably have to make compromises.  Write out the `SELECTs`.  Make sure you have indexes suitable for each `JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, RJ. All of your advice has been very helpful and, has  gotten me out of the ER box. I also was not aware that there is an enum type in sql!